# Does Glide, Picasso or other image loading library affects app's performance when loading image from local resources in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, picasso, android-glide

As the title stated, in my current apps, I have a case to load images from local resources to `RecyclerView`. Please note that **not** loading images from url, so no network required.

I do know that, if loading images from url, those image loading libraries will improve our app's performance because of their amazing optimized loading and caching features.

But, does that apply too when we load images from local resources?

I did found [this](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/731) resource, it did state that if we load only an image from local resources without any modification then we don't need this library.

So, how about if we load it in `RecyclerView` where we need to load lots of images from local resources? Does it improve our app's performance? Or `ImageView.setImageResource()` is enough?
Note that, there is a possibility the same image being reused.

Comment: Libraries, like the ones you mentioned, cache images into memory. If you don't cache images into memory, by only using `ImageView.setImageResource()`, you will run into `OutOfMemoryException` when loading larger images. I, most definitely, recomend using an image cache library like glide, picasso etc.

Comment: They will load as fast from local -or faster- as from network. They do not improve your apps performance. They only can make loading images faster. Or slower.

Comment: yes, that's true. But my concern here is more about the performance after using image library. Anyway, thanks for answering :) @HB.

Comment: Could you please explain more when loading the image faster and when is slower? @blackapps

Comment: @FranzAndel When loading an image for the first time using these libraries, it will be a few ms slower because it needs to be cached first. The second time it will load the same speed or faster than using `ImageView.setImageResource()` because the image is already in memory by the time you "load" it.

Comment: meaning the caching does applies too for loading image from local resources not only from networking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your images are stored in the `drawable` directories and you already have different sizes for different resolutions, then using another library for loading those images would not add much benefit.

However, if you have your images in `raw` or you don't have different sizes, just big ones, using something like Glide turns out to be quite useful, since it will resize down the image to fit the required space and stores the smaller image in the cache (memory or disk, depending on how you configure it). This considerably speeds up subsequent loads since the android UI doesn't need to do the scaling again.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer :)